# Подгрузка модального окна статьи (Modx)

Tags: html, ajax, cms, modx

Есть блок со статьями. Их может быть очень много. В блоке идёт название статьи картинка и краткое описание. При клике на статью открывается модальное окно с самой статьёй. В ней полный контент, картинки и всё прочее. Нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку показать модальное окно формировалось на лету. Для каждой статьи своё. Используется обычный вывод через pdoResources в чанках. Модальное окно находится в чанке оформления статьи (в блоках которая), но оно не должна подгружаться сразу ко всем, а только после нажатия кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте ajax запрос по клику, обращайтесь например к странице, где есть вызов к сниппету, который при получении ID страницы формирует тело модального окна/или просто передает назад "контент, картинки и все прочее"...получаете, обновляете содержимое модального окна, показываете. Это если в общем.